# How to search multiple patterns in each cell of two different dataframes in R

Tags: r

I have two dataframes

```
reference <- structure(list(GenomicPosition = c("rs63750445",  "rs63750847", "rs1259157720, rs63751666, rs63751263"), `Genomic Region` = c("CodingExon 16", "Coding Exon 16", "Coding Exon14")), row.names = 19:21, class = "data.frame")

map <- structure(list(GenomicPosition = c("rs63751666, rs1259157720", "rs63750445",  "rs6375886, rs63751263"), `Genomic Region` = c("CodingExon 16", "Coding exon 4", "Coding Exon 16")),  row.names = 19:21, class = "data.frame")
```

I wanted to know if there is any easy solution to look up multiple strings in one dataframe and check with multiple strings in another dataframe. Here I want to compare `rs[digits]` in column Genomic position of each dataframe and see if they have corresponding rsIDs in map dataframe.

The result I want is:

```
> map
GenomicPosition              Genomic Region           Matched_in_both_DF
rs63751666, rs1259157720      CodingExon 16            rs1259157720, rs63751666 
rs63750445                   Coding exon 4            rs63750445
rs6375886, rs63751263         Coding Exon 16           rs63751263
```

Comment: Have you looked into the `%in%` (infix) operator? Or are you looking for a merge/join operation?

Comment: @r2evans Yes, and I was thinking: Perhaps, first vectorizing all rsIDs in reference and looking up on map?

Comment: Should one of them be `Coding exon14` in `map` ?

Comment: @RonakShah I am not concerned for genomic region column (i.e Coding XXX) . Just need to check for `GenomicPosition` i.e.  rsXXX.

Comment: Is there a reason that the structure is maintained this way? That is, I might expect the two different positions to be in separate rows, not comma-separated within on cell. That's definitely making things less-trivial (though not impossible, just inconvenient).

Comment: @r2evans Yes, I need to grab elements starting with rs and vectorize them for look up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way splitting the strings on comma :

```
vec <- unlist(strsplit(reference$GenomicPosition, ',\\s*'))
map$Matched_in_both_DF <- sapply(strsplit(map$GenomicPosition, ',\\s*'), 
                                  function(x) toString(x[x %in% vec]))


map
#            GenomicPosition Genomic Region       Matched_in_both_DF
#19 rs63751666, rs1259157720  CodingExon 16 rs63751666, rs1259157720
#20               rs63750445  Coding exon 4               rs63750445
#21    rs6375886, rs63751263 Coding Exon 16               rs63751263
```